# Can I have a reference with spacing using bibtex? Like \cite{Author Year}

Tags: bibtex, citing

Can I have a bibtex entry with space in its key reference? Like below:

```
@article{Author 2000,
  title={Boring book},
  author={Boring Guy},
  journal={Boring Subject},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Bororing Pub.}
}
```

So my tex source can look like this and be recognized:

```
...the subject was well studied in \cite{Author 2000}.
```

Currently, if I run bibtex in this way I get an error:

```
White space in argument---line 67 of file file.aux
 : \citation{Author
 :                2000}
```

I understand what is the problem in this error, and I realise I can fix it going to my entries and changing it to an entry without the spacing. However, I was wondering if there was another solution.

**Can I cite references containing spacing? Like \cite{Author 2000}**

Comment: Neither spaces nor commas are allowed in the cotation keys. I would also stay away from non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @Mico Indeed, BibTeX(8) only allows ASCII chars in the key. While other tools (_e.g._ Biber) may handle accents in the key, this is 'non-standard' and should be avoided.

Answer (score 12):

> Can I have a bibtex entry with space in its key reference?

Neither spaces nor commas are allowed in the key references. (Recall that commas are the separator characters *between fields* in a bibtex entry.) Non-ASCII characters are not suitable either for use in key references if the bib file is processed by BibTeX(8).

Biber, which is newer than BibTeX, could *in principle* handle non-ASCII characters in the key reference. However, if preserving usability of the bib file with both BibTeX and Biber is an objective for you, you should definitely avoid using non-ASCII characters in the key reference.

Comment: The 5th upvote on this answer generated the overall 900th [!] badge I've received on this site!! Many thanks!!!