# Bibtex (natbib): Some Citation undefined

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

Some Citations in my file are undefined, even tough they are within my `.bib`-file. I can't find any error.

Here my logfile:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear-ibid, natbib=true,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}


\begin{document}


This citation works perfect: \citep{Arthur.}

(Most of my citation work)

This citation does not work: \citep{.Foucault 1980} 


\end{document}
```

And here is part of my .bib-file:

```
@book{.Foucault 1980,
 author = {Foucault, Michel},
 year = {1980},
 title = {Power/knowledge: Selected interviews and other writings 1972 - 1977},
 keywords = {Politische Philosophie},
 address = {New York},
 publisher = {{Vintage Books}},
 isbn = {039473954X}
}

@article{Arthur.,
 author = {Arthur, Paige},
 year = {2009},
 title = {How {\textquotedbl}Transition{\textquotedbl} Reshaped Human Rights: A Conceptual History of Transitional Justice},
 pages = {321--367},
 volume = {2009},
 number = {31 (2)},
 journal = {Human Rights Quarterly}
}
```

I know this one ["undefined citation warnings"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8332/undefined-citation-warnings), who states that the user should compile properly:

latex
bibtex
latex
latex

Clearly, this is not my problem, as some of the citations in my `.bib`-file work, while others don't. I also visited this one: [Latex Warning:Citation undefined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168312/latex-warning-citation-undefined), who couldn't solve my problem either.

Any suggestions? I really can't see the problem. I have around 80 citations, and from them about 15 just don't work.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You should avoid spaces in the cite key. Welcome to TeX.SX.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: Compiling your document using `bibtex`, I recieve the following error message: `White space in argument---line 9 of file  .aux : \citation{.Foucault : 1980} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command [...]` Also closely related: [Can I have a reference with spacing using bibtex? Like \cite{Author Year}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224674/134144)

Comment: Alright!! so easy... great, it works now. How can I upvote your comment?