# BibTeX referencing cannot find .aux file

Tags: bibtex, citing

I realise this is probably an easy fix, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get referencing to work (using TeXmaker for reference, though I doubt it makes a difference?) even after looking through several threads where people had similar issues. To my knowledge, I have followed every tutorial I've seen on using BibTeX correctly, but I am getting these errors.

Both `Project_Report_WIP.tex` and `Project_Report_WIP_References.bib` are saved in the same folder.

Here is `Project_Report_WIP.tex`

```
\begin{document}
...
Schoenemann and Steig (2016)\cite{Schoenemann and Steig (2016)}
...
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Project_report_WIP_References}
\end{document}
```

And here is `Project_Report_WIP_References.bib`

```
@article{schoenemann and Steig (2016),
    AUTHOR="John Doe",
    TITLE="The Book without Title",
    PUBLISHER="Dummy Publisher",
    YEAR="2100",
}
```

(currently just using a dummy example as it doesn't work yet anyway)

When I run quickbuild (Which is set to PdfLaTeX + BibTex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + View Pdf, as suggested by others who had a similar issue) on `Project_Report_WIP.tex` I get the following message:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) The top-level auxiliary file: Project_Report_WIP.aux White space in argument---line 24 of file Project_Report_WIP.aux : \citation{Schoenemann : and Steig 
(2016)} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command The style file: plain.bst I found no cite keys---
while reading file Project_Report_WIP.aux Database file #1: Project_report_WIP_References.bib I was 
expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 1 of file Project_report_WIP_References.bib : @article{schoenemann : and
 Steig (2016), I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

When I run BibTeX on `Project_report_WIP_References.bib`, I get:

```
I couldn't open file name `Project_Report_WIP_References.aux'

Process exited with error(s)
```

I cannot even *find* `Project_Report_WIP_References.aux`. Project_Report_WIP.aux exists, created in the same folder as all the other files, but Project_Report_WIP_References.aux was not created and can't therefore be opened.

Any help would be much appreciated. I do not know how to produce a .aux file for the .bib file if that is required

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't use spaces in your citation key.

Comment: See also this possible duplicate question: [Can I have a reference with spacing using bibtex? Like \cite{Author Year}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224674/134144)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You wrote, "When I run BibTeX on `Project_report_WIP_References.bib`,...". You should never, ever run BibTeX on the *bib file*. Assuming the main tex file is called `Project_Report_WIP.tex`, what you should do is execute `bibtex Project_Report_WIP`. (BibTeX will look for `Project_Report_WIP.aux` to find out what it's supposed to do.)